# Flake8 on VSCODE not highlighting errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

Simply make a file called test.py with following code:

```
print(x)
```

Running flake8 test.py shows the errors as expected:

```
test.py:1:7: F821 undefined name 'x'
```

Yet in VSCODE, nothing is being highlighted! Even on saving, it acts like everything is normal. How can I fix this?

My relevant settings:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.rulers": [
        88
    ],
    "sync.gist": "c39568aa1fdffb072eb23bbdcbb26f08",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "[json]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--ignore=E203",
        "--ignore=E266",
        "--ignore=E501",
        "--ignore=W503",
        "--max-line-length=88",
        "--select = B,C,E,F,W,T4,B9",
        "--max-complexity = 18"
    ],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons-darker",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "--login"
    ],
    "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.F": "Error",
    "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.E": "Error",
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "C:\\Users\\panda\\Documents\\classrosterbot\\crb2\\Scripts\\flake8"
}
```

Comment: Why are some `python.linting.flake8Args` formatted differently (spaces before and after `=`)? Is `python.linting.flake8Path` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `--ignore`, `--select`, and `--max-complexity` options are malformed

I believe you want this:

```json
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--extend-ignore=E203,E266,E501,W503",
        "--max-line-length=88",
        "--select=B,C,E,F,W,T4,B9",
        "--max-complexity=18"
    ],
```

with `--ignore`, the last one will win -- with spaces it will not be parsed properly

it's also usually better to specify these in the configuration file and *not* in your editor settings such that other tools and contributors can benefit without having to choose your IDE

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Could you confirm that this should still work? Since the settings does not change anything on my machine. The errors are not ignored, and the max line length is not changed.